# Redhat how can i use a space and double quote as separators to output the 2nd, 4th and last column from a each line in a file

Tags: awk, delimiter, double-quotes

I have the following multiple lines in a file on Linux, the line information differs but the format is always the same:

```
-item bread.maker -model "modelname model type modelnum-43453-23241.7" -date1 23.10.01 -date2 30.10.04 -date3 04.02.05
```

I want to output only the 2nd, 4th and last columns of each line. I've tried with `awk -F,` and `print $NF`, but I cannot seem get it to treat the double quoted part as 1 column.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

With any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/"[^"]*"/){print $2, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH), $NF}' file
bread.maker "modelname model type modelnum-43453-23241.7" 04.02.05
```

or:

```
$ awk -v OFS='"' '{split($0,f,/"/); print $2, f[2], $NF}' file
bread.maker"modelname model type modelnum-43453-23241.7"04.02.05
```

or with GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^" ]+|"[^"]*"' '{print $2, $4, $10}'  file
bread.maker "modelname model type modelnum-43453-23241.7" 04.02.05
```

Set `OFS` as appropriate if you want something other than a blank char to separate the output fields. I used `"` as the OFS for the 2nd script since it must not be present in your input if you're already using it to quote strings.

Comment: That works great.  Any chance you can explain what it's doing, so I can potentially use it again in the future with different data ?

Comment: I think if you thought about it for a minute (and maybe looked up `match()`, `substr()`, `split()`, and/or `FPAT` in the man page) it'd be very clear what any of those scripts are doing so please take a minute to investigate and think about it and then please feel free to come back and ask if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

With bash v5.1, we can assign an even-numbered list of words as an associative array: it will be treated as a key-value list.

```sh
declare -A fields

while IFS= read -r line; do
    eval fields=("$line")      # yeah, eval is needed here to respect
                               # the quotes in the line
    printf '%s,%s,%s\n' "${fields[-item]}" "${fields[-model]}" "${fields[-date3]}"
done < file
```

```
bread.maker,modelname model type modelnum-43453-23241.7,04.02.05
```